# Structural subtyping in macro

Tags: haxe, structural-typing

This function to map JSON objects gets `@:build`-ed. It works fine when there's only one JSON-file or if all files share the same field structure. But when the objects' structures differ, I get structural subtyping errors *("Object requires field xxx")*. On top of that, the order of the objects matter sometimes.

I don't get why it's type checking; you'd think they would be anon objects and left alone. Can anyone see if I'm not doing something correctly; otherwise I'll make an issue on Github.

```
public static function build():Array<Field> {

    var fields = Context.getBuildFields();

    // Object requires field "deep"
    var files = ['{"name": "Test1", "id": { "deep" : 5 }}','{"name": "Test0","id": {}}'];

    // no error
    // var files = ['{"name": "Test0","id": {}}','{"name": "Test1", "id": { "deep" : 5 }}'];

    var a:Array<Expr> = [];
    for (s in files) {
        var o = Context.parseInlineString(s, Context.currentPos());
        a.push({ expr : EBinop(OpArrow, macro $v{s}, o), pos : Context.currentPos() });
    }

    var newfield:Field = {
        name : "files", doc : null, meta : [], access : [AStatic, APublic], pos : Context.currentPos(),
        // map array decl: [x => y]
        kind : FVar(macro : StringMap<Dynamic>, { expr : EArrayDecl(a), pos : Context.currentPos() } )
    };

    fields.push(newfield);

    return fields;
}
```

I'm using *Haxe 3.2.0-rc2*.

Comment: It is not related to macros. It is just a problem of how haxe handles structural subtyping in collections. It is in fact a bit inconsistent and I've just reported the issue at https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4196